# PHP assistance to send an email from a contact form

Tags: php, forms, email

So i have a website I've built for a friend. The trouble I'm having is getting php to send an email from the entries within the contact form. I have it hosted on a paid server.

Anyway, heres the contact form within index.html:

```
`<form class="form-horizontal" id="rsvpForm" role="form" method="post" action="rsvp.php">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
       <div class="form-group">
            <label for="guestName">Name(s)</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="guest_name" id="guestName" placeholder="Name(s)">
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
         <div class="form-group">
             <label for="response">Response</label>
             <textarea class="form-control" name="response" id="response" placeholder="Response"></textarea>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
         <div class="form-group">
             <label for="diet">Please include any special dietary requirements</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" name="diet" rows="5" id="diet"></textarea>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-6">
            <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="R.S.V.P." class="btn tf-btn btn-default">
         </div>
    </div>
```

`

And the rsvp.php file that does not appear to do anything -

```
'<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

    $guest_name = $_POST['guest_name'];
    $response = $_POST['response'];
    $diet = $_POST['diet'];
    $to = 'example@xyz.com';
    $subject = 'Wedding';


    $message = $_POST["From : $guest_name\n Response : $response\n Special Dietary Requirements : $diet"];


    if ($_POST) {
        mail ($to, $subject, $message);
        http_response_code(501);
    }

} else {
    // Generate 400 response because required query params are missing.
    http_response_code(400);
}
?>'
```

Any idea as to why the php is not firing the email off when i click submit?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks John, I'll check that out

Comment: Apart from the somewhat effortful `mail.log` inspection you'll have to do (best to contact your hoster for support on such things), there's also a mistake with your `$message` string. Don't wrap `$_POST[ … ]` around the `= "From: ... $diet.";` text assignment. (You'd get a helpful notice with error_reporting enabled.)